# How to get local time c++

Tags: c++

I need to get the current time (hour,minutes and seconds) and add 30 minutes. In final i need to save the result to an integer variable.

How it's possible to do?

My code at the moment:

```
int main()
{

  time_t currentTime;
  struct tm *localTime;

  time( &currentTime );
  localTime = localtime( &currentTime );

  int Hour   = localTime->tm_hour;
  int Min    = localTime->tm_min;
  int Sec    = localTime->tm_sec;

  std::cout << "Execute at: " << Hour << ":" << Min << ":" << Sec << std::endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your expected output? Do you mean increase time by 30 minute and print output?

Comment: My expected output is the current local data time (hour:min:ss) plus 30minutes

For example

Current time: 13:16:50
What i want: 13:46:50

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following to get time 30 minutes ahead of local time:

```
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *localTime;
    time( &currentTime );
    currentTime += 1*30*60;
    localTime= localtime(&utc);
```

The localTime structure now has 30 minutes ahead of current local time.You can get the values in integers as you were doing before.

```
    int Hour   = localTime->tm_hour;
    int Min    = localTime->tm_min;
    int Sec    = localTime->tm_sec;
```

In case you need string out of it,you can do

```
    std::string strAheadTime = asctime(localTime);
```

Comment: Thanks. Its not possible to convert the final result to integer?

Comment: My expected output is the current local data time (hour:min:ss) plus 30minutes For example Current time: 13:16:50 What i want: 13:46:50

Comment: do you want the format hh:mm:ss in an integer,is that what you are trying to say? you can get the seconds since epoch in int but not time_t in the format you want

Comment: you can get a string in hh:mm:ss though

Comment: Ok, i will explain all my objective :)

I'm doing an API that generate random sessionId with expiration date 30 minutes. When i create a sessionId (for example in this time: 13:48:00) i need to increase 30 min at this time,that is 14:18:00, and the sessionId are created. 

But in other function i receive the sessionId and i need to check the expiration date, so i need to compare the current date (for example: 14:30:00) and compare to the sessionId expiration date. You understand what i need?

Comment: Yeah i got u. I have a couple of questions before i can provide u the solution. The session id u recieve is what data type? is it a string or time_t? second,do u use boost? third,do u use c++11?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
 time_t currentTime;
 struct tm *localTime;

 time( &currentTime );                   // Get the current time
 localTime = localtime( &currentTime );  // Convert the current time to the local time

 int Hour   = localTime->tm_hour;
 int Min    = localTime->tm_min;
 int Sec    = localTime->tm_sec;

 std::cout << "The current time is : " << Hour << ":" << Min << ":" << Sec << std::endl;

 //increase local time by 30 minutes and adjust minutes and hour.
 int IncMin = Min + 30;
 if(IncMin >= 60){
   int res = IncMin/60;
   int newMin = IncMin % 60;
   Hour += res;
   if(Hour > 23){
      Hour = 00;
   }
   std::cout << "The updated time is : " << Hour << ":" << newMin << ":" << Sec << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```